# JSP forced file initialization on Google App Engine not working

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

If you have an HTML filed listed as the forced JSP file, you may see error:

```
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyLogger warn: Failed startup of context
Caused by: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: No class in holder client
```

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to use a static HTML file for a forced path JSP file. A static HTML file is not precompiled and at runtime, jetty is unable to find the precompiled JSP. It looks for a servlet called "jsp", which it can use as the servlet class. It will result in a "No class in holder" error because no servlet class is found.